# Determine standard matrix for the following map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ defined by the equation $x+2y+2z=0$. Let $T: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be the projection onto $H$

Now Determine the standard matrix of the map $T$.

The place where I am struggling is how can I find $T$ and to find standard I think I just need to find image of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ under $T$

Comment: This question gives several ways of doing this. And also has warning about saying "the" projection, there are many. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726534/calculate-the-matrix-for-the-projection-of-r3-onto-the-plane-xyz-0

Answer (score 0):

There are several projections into the plane $H$. You can project along any direction that is not parallel to the plane. I suggest you search for the orthogonal projection.
As you mentioned, we have to find the image of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ under $T$.
First, we compute the direction $p$ which is orthogonal to your plane. In this case, it is very easy and just $p^T=(1,2,2)^T$, since $(1,2,2)^Tx=0$ for all $x$ in your plane.
So the projection $T$ should move $e_1$ along p until we are on the plane, i.e.
\begin{align*}
0\overset{!}=(1,2,2)\left(e_1+\lambda_1 p\right)=(1,2,2)\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right)+\lambda_1\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\2\end{array}\right)\right).
\end{align*}
It follows
\begin{align*}
1+\lambda_1+4\lambda_1+4\lambda_1=0\Leftrightarrow \lambda_1=-\frac19.
\end{align*}
thus the image of $e_1$ under $T$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right)-\frac19\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\2\end{array}\right)\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac89\\-\frac29\\-\frac29\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
Analogously you get
\begin{align*}
Te_2&=\left(\begin{array}{c}-\frac29\\\frac59\\-\frac49\end{array}\right)\\
Te_3&=\left(\begin{array}{c}-\frac29\\-\frac49\\ \frac59\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
Summarizing we get
\begin{align*}
T&=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac89&-\frac29&-\frac29\\-\frac29&\frac59&-\frac49\\-\frac29&-\frac49&\frac59\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
Of course, this is not rigorous proof that $T$ is the orthogonal projection into $H$. Therefore you should prove that $T$ fulfills the properties of an orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid coordinates as long as possible.

Let $n=(1,2,2)$, then $\|n\|^2=9$.  The projection of a point $p$ on the plane given by $\langle n,x\rangle=0$ is
$$p-\langle\frac{n}{\|n\|},p\rangle\frac{n}{\|n\|}=p-\frac{n}{\|n\|^2}\langle n,p\rangle
=p-\frac{1}{9}\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\2\end{pmatrix},p\right\rangle\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$
For the column vectors of $T$ substitute $p$ by the unit vectors.